# How to use SQL UNION with Ignite Caches

Tags: java, sql, union, ignite, gridgain

I was having a ignite cache and doing sql queries as follows.

```
    IgniteCache<String, ClassName> cache = ignite.cache(CACHE_NAME);
    private static final String sql = "Select timestamp from cache1 where  orderId = ? and timestamp <= ? and timestamp >= ? ";
    SqlFieldsQuery sqlQ = new SqlFieldsQuery(sql).setArgs(id, t1, t2);
        try (QueryCursor<List<?>> cursor = cache.query(sqlQ)) {
            for (List<?> row : cursor) {
                    timestamps.add((Long) row.get(0));          
            }
```

Now I want to query from two different caches and get the union. I was able to successfully write the SQL union operation.

```
private static final String sqlTwoCaches = "Select timestamp from cache1 union all Select timestamp from cache2 order by timestamp";
```

I want to add the timestamp results from both caches to a single arraylist. I want to know how to use the query cursor? Now there are two caches and how to do the this part? `(QueryCursor<List<?>> cursor = cache.query(sqlTwoCaches))`

Or is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to "fully qualify" the second cache name, but otherwise, it should Just Work.

Example:

```
IgniteCache<String, ClassName1> cache1 = ignite.cache("table1");
IgniteCache<String, ClassName2> cache2 = ignite.cache("table2");
private static final String sql = "select timestamp from ClassName1 UNION ALL select timestamp from table2.ClassName2 ";
SqlFieldsQuery sqlQ = new SqlFieldsQuery(sql);
try (QueryCursor<List<?>> cursor = cache1.query(sqlQ)) {
    for (List<?> row : cursor) {
            timestamps.add((Long) row.get(0));          
    }
 }
```

Comment: Not clear what you said. Could you please explain it?

Comment: Got it. If I have a third cache like this, `IgniteCache<String, ClassName3> cache3 = ignite.cache("table3");` Can I do this?
`private static final String sql = "select timestamp from ClassName1 UNION ALL select timestamp from table2.ClassName2 UNION ALL select timestamp from table3.ClassName3";`
`SqlFieldsQuery sqlQ = new SqlFieldsQuery(sql);`
`try (QueryCursor<List<?>> cursor = cache1.query(sqlQ)) { .... `

Comment: Your method is not forking. It gives following error. `CacheException: Failed to parse query. Schema "UNCONFIRMED_EVENT_URGENT_MC_79" not found; 
:`  Here is the SQL query.
`sql = "Select _val from UnconfirmedEvent where orderId = ? and startTime < ? and endTime > ? and type = %s UNION ALL " +
                    "Select _val from " + String.format(UNCONFIRMED_URGENT_EVENT_CACHE,mcId) + ".UnconfirmedEvent where orderId = ? and startTime < ? and endTime > ? and type = %s " + " order by startTime"; `

Comment: It's saying that there's no cache with the name you've given. Which caches are listed when you call `Ignite#cacheNames()`?

Comment: `UNCONFIRMED_EVENT_URGENT_MC_79` and `UNCONFIRMED_EVENT_MC_79` caches were available in the ignite when calling this.

Comment: This is how I define the caches. 
`IgniteCache<String, UnconfirmedEvent> unconfirmedEventCache = ignite.cache(String.format(UNCONFIRMED_NON_URGENT_EVENT_CACHE,mcId));
        IgniteCache<String, UnconfirmedEvent> unconfirmedUrgentEventCache = ignite.cache(String.format(UNCONFIRMED_URGENT_EVENT_CACHE,mcId));`